# Are comments at the top of a source file a bad idea?

Tags: comments

I use Xcode to edit my source files, and typically a file will look like this

```
//
//  Queue.swift
//  SomeCompany
//
//  Created by Someone (Job Title) on 26/06/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 SomeCompany. All rights reserved.
//

/// A queue is a list where you can only insert new items at the back and remove items from the front. 
/// This ensures that the first item you enqueue is also the first item you dequeue. 
/// First come, first serve!
struct Queue<T> {
    ...
}
```

Are comments at the top of a source file a bad idea? The bit I am specifically talking about is:

- The filename
- The company name
- The author, and the date it was created
- The copyright information

I am rather dubious about the whole thing since all of the information is available in git, except the copyright information.

I would prefer the whole thing to be trimmed.

```
//
//  Copyright © 2017 SomeCompany. All rights reserved.
//

/// A queue is a list where you can only insert new items at the back and remove items from the front. 
/// This ensures that the first item you enqueue is also the first item you dequeue. 
/// First come, first serve!
struct Queue<T> {
    ...
}
```

Work colleagues think I am being irrational as they believe original author is useful to know who originally created the file, and when they created it - but my argument is that it becomes out of date as soon as someone edits it (plus, all that information is available in vcs anyway)

I want to know if it seems sensible to get rid of the filename, company and author information.

Comment: IMHO: You need the copyright, company name & any legalese (usually disclaimers) required in your jurisdiction. Anything else is optional.

Comment: In my view this is purely opinion-based. I hate, hate, hate having to wade through any sort of comments before I get to the code. Others like explanatory comments. Still others seem to love polluting their code with copyright guff (which, as far as I know, can be put into a separate file and have it satisfy any jurisdiction).

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time before file versioning, keeping basic header information such as what the class does, when it was created, and by whom was somewhat necessary.  If something didn't work, you needed to be able to contact the programmer that made it if, for no other reason, than to give him a thorough telling off.

Nowadays, file versioning has done away with most of this information, but old habits die hard.  It may still even be useful to provide a brief summary of what the class or file does/defines, as nobody is going to kill you in your sleep for writing *excessive* comments though you may get a few eye rolls.

My thoughts are that if headers are present throughout a project, it is better to be consistent, even if you think it is silly and unnecessary.  Otherwise, focus on making the code clear and concise rather than filling the lines inbetween with commentary.  Only if the code is unclear (may the programming gods save us all) should you write a few lines explaining it to the best of your ability.

Comment: how does VCS answer the "what does it do" question?

Comment: @NickKeighley, the code should answer the "what does it do?" question. Writing comments to explain bad code is not really a very good substitute for writing better code.

Comment: @NickKeighley The question isn't about documentation. Documentation is sensible.  The question is about meta-information like copyright, license, authorship, change tracking, file name, ….

Comment: code rarely answers the "what does it do" in my observation. I prefer a comment explaining what a class is for.

Comment: The comment I was responding to *specifically* mentioned "what the class does".

Comment: As a rule, I never comment code unless I think a 2nd glance at it at a later date will require clarification. The corollary being that you need to write clean descriptive code. For the example, if I look at a Queue and then find out it's behaving like a Stack, I am not going to look at header comments, I am heading to VCS to find out who named it a Queue so we can discuss nomenclature. If I cannot look at a class (or non OOP file structure) and its members and have a good idea what it is doing, I think there are larger issues at play than descriptive comments.

Comment: @NickKeighley VCS provide information relative to why the file was created, what changes have been made to it for any given change, and in essence, provides all basic header information relative to who last changed it and when.

Comment: The Queue/Stack example is obviously silly. What does a RotaryLabeller class do?

Comment: @NickKeighley Clearly a RotaryLabeller labels Rotaries.  ;)